# How do I say "sure" sarcastically/with lots of skepticism?

Tags: traduction

In English I find very frequently that when replying to a question like "do you like my new shirt?" I tend to say "sure" but drag out the word to indicate that I don't want to lie and that I don't really like the new shirt but I am trying to protect their feelings. The typical translation for "sure" as far as I know is « bien sûr » but I have never heard someone use this sarcastically/with the opposite meaning. Is it possible to manipulate how you say « bien sûr » to indicate sarcasm or is there a different word(s) altogether?

Just for further clarification, the type of "sure" I want to translate would happen in a conversation as follows:

"Hey John, do you want to go to Indonesia this year during Christmas?"
"Sure..."
"Ok well... How about Bhutan?"

Comment: *Sûrement, oui* ou * C'est ça, oui*. Ce que j'utilise...

Comment: À noter que l'expression *C'est cela oui* a été popularisée par le film *Le père Noël est une ordure*. D'actualité donc.

Comment: I agree with "c'est cela, oui", and I'll even add that it will probably never be used non-sarcastically.

Comment: Oui, c'est ça. can be said with a sarcastic tone.

Answer (score 2):

If you say *bien sûr* in an ironical tone, with a smirk, it means you entirely disbelief what you are being told, and it usually is disrespectful, which is not what this non-committal "sure" is. To my knowledge French doesn't have one single word or expression to bring out this idea of the English "sure". I gather we have lots of ways to express this idea and they probably imply different degrees of approval. I think it's better to answer as a [Community wiki](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) so that we can all add our own perception of this "sure".

*Ouais* ! Most often said *mouais* and dragging out the word.
*Pourquoi pas* !
*Ça peut aller* !
*Ça peut le faire* ! (almost always pronounced [sapølfɛʁ]).
*Bof* !